# How to use Python to get all cookies from web?

Tags: python, python-requests

Input

```
import requests
from http import cookiejar
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}
url = "http://www.baidu.com/"
session = requests.Session()
req = session.put(url = url,headers=headers)
cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(req.cookies)
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
print(cookie)
```

Gives output:
    {'BAIDUID': '323CFCB910A545D7FCCDA005A9E070BC:FG=1', 'BDSVRTM': '0'}
    {'BAIDUID': '323CFCB910A545D7FCCDA005A9E070BC:FG=1'}

[as here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j44LN.png)

I try to use this code to get all cookies from the Baidu website but only return the first cookie. I compare it with the original web cookies(in the picture), it has 9 cookies. How can I get all the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't maintain your session, so it terminated after the second cookie.

```
import requests
from http import cookiejar

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}
url = "http://www.baidu.com/"

with requests.Session() as s:
    req = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(req.cookies.get_dict())
```

```
>> print(req.cookies.get_dict().keys())
>>> ['BDSVRTM', 'BAIDUID', 'H_PS_PSSID', 'BIDUPSID', 'PSTM', 'BD_HOME']
```